# How do I test a ranking system?

Tags: validation, testing, dataset, automated-tests, functional-testing

Let us assume we have 3 students in a class and secured the below marks

```
===============================================
|      | Maths  | English  | Science  | Rank  |
|----------------------------------------------
|Mark  |   60   |    40    |    80    |   2   |
|----------------------------------------------
|John  |   40   |    30    |    50    |   3   |
|----------------------------------------------
|Alice |   60   |    60    |    70    |   1   |
===============================================
```

Normally the rank is decided by adding all three marks.
Looking at the above table, the rank sequence would be Alice, Mark, John.

If there exists a system that takes student marks as input and gives out the list of student names based on their rank, then how do I certify that the system returns correct student list for all possible data set?

What should be the approach to test such a system? Generating all possible combinations of data would be exhaustive when the number of students and subjects increase.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is black box testing, I would approach the testing task like this:

- Verify that ranking actually works on a simple data set (smoke testing)
- Verify ranking works when 2 or more students score the same
- Verify that ranking calculation works when data set contains students with missing marks, a negative mark (if possible!?) or a mark larger than allowed
- Given the context (students and subjects) I assume a realistic data set is possible to create. Verify this is processed correctly.
- Create a second data set where the number of students and subjects are unrealistic (e.g. 100 % larger than your realistic data set) - try throwing that at it :)
- A dataset missing a student name, but subject marks are present for the row
- Same as above, but with missing subject, but marks for it are present for all rows
- An data set without marks, but with students and subjects

Based on the tests I suggest above, I would not worry above all possible data combinations. Nevertheless, if you have code access, unit test tools like xUnit can help you test all possible combinations (if you define the parameters)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above:

- border case - when marks are on the border - 0 , 100
- border case - marks are different, but the rank is the same - for first, last, middle student
- border case - duplicate names or subjects (a class with 2 Johns for example)
- error case - names or subject are present but invalid (digit, empty string, null, etc)